# How to code an if loop to create a new string itself

Tags: python, discord.py

I need to create a string every time the user calls a specific function is called up.
A new string needs to be created with the user's name as its name
But the name consists of Name#1234 so I need to separate the part after # too.
Can anyone write a function to do these 2 things? I'd be really grateful

Comment: pls tel us what you have tried so far.

Comment: if is a statement and not a loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

`name.split("#")` will give you a list of strings that is separated by `"#"` so `"abc#def#ghi"` becomes `["abc", "def", ghi"]`
To put the list back into a string do `"#".join(["abc", "def", ghi"])` which will give you `"abc#def#ghi"`
 to isolate everything in the string before the last # because their username might have a # in it, you do `"#".join(name.split("#")[:-1])`, to get just the numbers after the #, you do `name.split("#")[-1]`.
The index `-1` means the last item in the list

Comment: Gunesh Shubhang i'm not able to find anything on how to create a variable which is why I asked. Instead of asking me my research maybe tell an answer

Comment: I meant cresste a varibale in the code, i know how to create a varibale nomrally